# Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError Requested entity was not found. [404]

Tags: google-sheets-api

when use

```
SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.UpdateRequest request = service.Spreadsheets.Values.Update(requestBody, spreadsheetId, range);
            request.ValueInputOption = valueInputOption;

            // To execute asynchronously in an async method, replace `request.Execute()` as shown:
            Data.UpdateValuesResponse response = request.Execute();
```

got this error

```
Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError Requested entity was not found. [404]
```

Answer (score 2):

You check your spreadsheetID if it is valid or not. Your error is "Requested entity was not found. [404]", [404] is caused by the invalid spreadsheetID. The server side cannot find the corresponding spreadsheet by the spreadsheetID.

**References:**

API. See the C# part:
https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update

SpreadsheetID. See the SpreadsheetID part:
https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me when I clicked on `Configure scope` and checkboxed the ones I'm using
[image]